# The given key was not present in the dictionary x:Arguments Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on `MasterDetailPage`. In `MasterDetailPage.Master` section I have created `ListView` manually. But in  `MasterDetailPage.Detail` I am using other `Page` of type `TabbedPage`. This

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
<NavigationPage>
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:HomePage2 />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

The `local` variable declared on top of page. View has `HomePage2` file

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProjectXamarin.View"
```

Code `<local:HomePage2 />` shows me compilation error

> The given key was not present in the dictionary

This is HomePage2 file **`.cs`**

```
public partial class HomePage2 : TabbedPage
{
    public HomePage2(string btnName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "Home Page";
        //BindingContext = new HomePageViewModel();
    }
}
```

**`.xaml`**

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestProjectXamarin.View"            
         x:Class="TestProjectXamarin.View.HomePage2">

<TabbedPage.Children>
    <NavigationPage Title="Games" Icon="games">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:GamesTab/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Movies" Icon="camera">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:MoviesTab />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

If I create `Xamarin.Forms` project with build-in `MasterDetailPage` template the same type of code working. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is the lack of a **parameterless constructor**.

Given you don't appear to be using your parameter, I'd suggest changing:

```
public HomePage2(string btnName)
```

to:

```
public HomePage2()
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass require `param`?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/XAML/PassingConstructorArguments/ or https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63604/passing-argments-into-tabbed-pages-from-host-page may help @CGPA6.4.