# Passing data to other page using Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am starting new `Page` using `Activator.CreateInstance`

```
private void OnMenuSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (item.Title == "Movies")
    {
        //Type page = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem.TargetType; 
        //page is HomePage           
        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
    }
}
```

**`HomePage.xaml.cs`**

```
public partial class HomePage : TabbedPage
{
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //if (MenuName == "Movies")
        //this.CurrentPage = Children[1];
    }
}
```

I want to send data from `Activator.CreateInstance` to `MenuName`, How can I do that?
I can't use `constructor` due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375067/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-xarguments-xamarin-forms/53375237?noredirect=1#comment93626197_53375237) issue.

Comment: You can pass arguments in constructor when using `Activator.CreateInstance`, but this feels quite dirty to me.

Comment: @DavidG - I forgot to mention, I cant pass argument in constructor due to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375067/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-xarguments-xamarin-forms/53375237?noredirect=1#comment93626197_53375237

Comment: Do all pages have a `MenuName` property?

Comment: No, only `HomePage`.

Comment: Then how do you know you need to set that property from the `OnMenuSelected` event?

Comment: @DavidG why is using the constructor dirty?

Comment: @AlexanderUddfeldt Using a constructor is not dirty, but messing around with `Activator.CreateInstance` usually is.

Comment: @DavidG - I have list of side menus(`MasterDetailPage`). When I click on Movie menu than I should Navigate to tab 2. You can check  commented code of HomePage.

Comment: Using `Activator.CreateInstance` you can pass parameters to constructors aswell. It might feel a bit dirty perhaps. I have done it in similar situation in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just set the MenuName property (it is public) after instantiating the HomePage? e.g.:

```
private void OnMenuSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (item.Title == "Movies")
    {
        Type page = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem.TargetType; 
        //page is HomePage  
        var pageInstance = (HomePage)Activator.CreateInstance(page)
        pageInstance.MenuName = item.Title;
        Detail = new NavigationPage(pageInstance);
    }
}
```

If that won't work, please explain why?

**EDIT** (after getting test project):

You are setting MenuName after you created the instance of HomePage:

```
if (item.Title == "Movies")
{               
    Type page = item.TargetType;
    var pageInstance = (HomePage)Activator.CreateInstance(page);
    // So now you already have your HomePage and you already checked 
    // in HomePage constructor for the value of MenuName, but it has
    // not been set yet, as it is set on the next line:
    pageInstance.MenuName = item.Title;
    Detail = new NavigationPage(pageInstance);
    IsPresented = false;
}
```

but checking the value of MenuName in the HomePage constructor, i.e. before you set he menu name:

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();         
    if (MenuName == "Movies")
    {
        this.CurrentPage = Children[1];
    }
}
```

Maybe check for the MenuName in an OnAppearing override instead:

```
public partial class HomePage : TabbedPage
{
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if (MenuName == "Movies")
        {
            this.CurrentPage = Children[1];
        }
    }
}
```

The above seems to work as expected.

Comment: This is not working. After setting value to `MenuName` when control going to `HomePage`s constructor, from there directly jumping to associated tab(Tab1 & Tab2) Page's constructor. When returning control to `HomePage` by than `MenuName` turned to `null`.

Comment: Then somehow when returning control to HomePage, you are creating a new instance of HomePage. I would need to see more code, ideally a test project that reproduces the issue.

Comment: This is the repository of my project. Please ignore viewmodel folder as I am not using. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoU8wqJTZgnPqxWdkKHb-FWMHxih

Comment: Also wondering why you are mixing navigation paradigms here, i.e. TabbedPage in a MasterDetailPage? I would make a separate Games and Movies pages rather than having Games and Movies pages share one TabbedPage, but that is just me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer It's working for me. Why I am mixing those because, so many app's are out there using combination of `MasterDetailPage` & `TabbedPage` for Ex. Google Play store app. I might be following wrong procedure of doing it but this architecture is acceptable. Even I have written article on this. Have a look https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-masterdetailpage-with-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create base page which inheret from TabbedPage with virtual method `Initialize()`

```
public class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
    public virtual void Initialize(object parameters)
    {

    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
 private void OnMenuSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            //Type page = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem.TargetType; 
            //page is HomePage           
            var page = (Page) Activator.CreateInstance(page);
            Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
            if (page is MyTabbedPage tabbedPage)
                tabbedPage.Initialize(params);
        }

public partial class HomePage : MyTabbedPage
    {
        public string MenuName { get; set; }
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //if (MenuName == "Movies")
            //this.CurrentPage = Children[1];
        }

        public override void Initialize(object parameters)
        {
            //Stuff
        }
    }
```

Change the XAML side also to MyTabbedPage

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can't I do it in more easier way.

Comment: Of course You can just define the method in your HomePage and change  if (page is HomePage homePage)
                homePage.Initialize(params);

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: maybe not best idea...

Using `Activator.CreateInstance`. You could do something like this:

```
private void OnMenuSelected(object sender, CustomArgstype args)
{
    var parameter = args.MenuName;
    if (parameter != null)
    {
        page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameter);
    }
    else
    {
        page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `CustomArgstype` & how it has `MenuName`?

Comment: CustomArgstype is a new type that you create to suit your needs!

Comment: Yeah! It seems diffecult . Now I am planning to use state management